# how to create an image from matrix of colours in swift?

Tags: ios, image, swift

I have to create an image from a matrix of colours. The colors are expressed in hexadecimal. 
Example:

`[ffffff 000000 000000
 ffffff 000000 ffffff
 000000 ffffff 000000]`

I have this code:

```
struct Matrix
{
    let rows: Int, columns: Int
    var grid: [String]

    init (rows: Int, columns: Int)
    {
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        grid = Array(count: rows * columns, repeatedValue: "")

    }

    func indexIsValidForRow(row: Int, column: Int) -> Bool
    {
        return row >= 0 && row < rows && column >= 0 && column < columns
    }

    subscript(row: Int, column: Int) -> String
    {
        get {
            assert(indexIsValidForRow(row, column: column), "Index out range")
            return grid[(row * columns) + column]

        }

        set {
            assert(indexIsValidForRow(row, column: column), "Index out range")
            grid[(row * columns) + column] = newValue

        }
    }
}

var matrix = Matrix(rows: 512, columns: 512) //After this line I will add the colours in this matrix
```

Thank You

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by a `matrix`? Is it something visual? Nested arrays? And more importantly, what have you tried? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create bitmap with CGBitmapContextCreate(), populate it with your data and create UIImage like this:

```
CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(...);
// populate bitmap with data

// create UIImage from bitmap
CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

// release resources
CGContextRelease(bitmap);
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

Bitmap format and how to populate depends on your raw data.

Update #1

```
var matrix = Matrix(rows: 64, columns: 64) // After this line I will add the colours in this matrix

let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue) | CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little;
var bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, matrix.columns, matrix.rows, 8, 0, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)

var bitmapData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>(CGBitmapContextGetData(bitmap))
for var i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++
{
    for var j = 0; j < matrix.columns; j++
    {
        // constant used with format RGBA
        bitmapData[matrix.rows * i + j] = 0x00ff00ff
    }
}

let imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap)
let image = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)
```

Your current implementation is hard to use because of string value. You need to use integer values for matrix, like `UInt32`. In my example I use constant value for color.